# Cannot start postgres as Service from Program Files folder

Tags: windows, postgresql, service, permissions

This is somewhat an update to [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924913/how-to-install-postgres-with-nsis-with-all-parameters) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936467/executing-batch-file-for-postgre-dbinit-with-nsis-gives-permission-denied). After realizing that postgres could be bundled with its database already initialized, and even with mock-up data inside (yay) I modified my NSIS installer to just copy-paste the postgres inside the installation folder of my application and then create and start it as a Service listening to a non-standard port.

The problem is that when the application is installed in the `Program Files` folder the Service is created, but cannot start. Either from the command line or from the Services Windows Dialog I get the following error:

> The My App Postgre Server service on Local Computer started
>   and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in
>   use by other services or programs.

If postgre is installed outside system folders, e.g. `D:\My App\pgsql\` everything works fine - the service starts and the database is accessible trough my application.

This seems like a permission issue, but I can't get around it.

Comment: Did you, as Craig Ringer suggested, switch the data directory to somewhere under %PROGRAMDATA%\ ? Where is the logfile going to, and ifit exists, what does it say? In short, I suspect that it still tries to write in its installation directory, which is an issue for %PROGRAMFILES% in newer Windows.

Comment: Changing the folder to %PROGRAMDATA% gives the same error. I actually get this error even if I manually copy-paste only the pgsql folder and manually try to create and start as a Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now all the information I have encountered points that Postgres cannot be started from the `Program Files` or any other System folder. I have seen other similar applications using it and installing it `C:\postgres` in order to make it work.